# Resolving readEither on ADT

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types, either

Hello i was wondering if given an `Algebraic Data Type` how can i resolve the following problem :

```
u::Text->String
u =Data.Text.unpack

 data Numeric=I Int | D Double

 readNumeric::Text->Either String Numeric
 readNumeric text=let str=u text in
                      if '.' `elem` str then 
                       D (readEither str::Either String Double)
                      else
                       I (readEither str::Either String Int)
```

How can i cover both `sides` of `Either` given an `ADT`? Practically `2*2` 
  cases , uniformly?

I was considering using `fromRight` on each branch ( e.g `fromRight (D 0)` ) of the `pattern-matching` 
  (in our case if since there are only 2 cases) but i do not know if it is the 
  best approach . 
  But `fromRight` returns the inner type..i want to preserve the `Either`

Any ideas?

Comment: `fmap D :: Either a Double -> Either a Numeric`. The same for `I`.

Comment: Do you really care if the value is *exactly* an `Int` or a `Double`? You can simply use `readNumeric :: (Num a, Read a) => Either String a; readNumeric = readEither` to get *any* value that has both a `Read` and `Num` instance (which includes both `Int` and `Double`).

Comment: I care when  the value is an `Int` in one case , the rest i do not care.I supplied `Double` because i didn't think of other `Haskell` predefined types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this is what you need?

```
readNumeric::Text -> Either String Numeric
readNumeric text=let str = u text in
                      if '.' `elem` str then 
                       fmap D (readEither str::Either String Double)
                      else
                       fmap I (readEither str::Either String Int)
```

Comment: I was trying just applying `D` without `fmap`.I didn't know the `fmap` is implemented to apply the given method if the result is `Right`.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian it is also useful for you to know about `either` for those cases where you want to "map" the `Left` case or both `Left` and `Right`. You can map both with `either f g`, the `f` maps the left and `g` maps the right. So `fmap D = either id D`.

Comment: I do not understand the following: If my result can be a `Double` or a `String` , when the result is indeed a `string` ,  who tells `fmap` perform the `D` on the `Right` and nothing on the `Left` ?

Comment: fmap always transform Right. In case of Left it live it as is.

Comment: Oh  but i want to know more specifically where do you find the information on how `fmap` behaves on these monads ?Is there like a documentation or a source for `fmap` ?

Comment: There is thing called "hoogle"(don't remember URL, just Google it) it allow to search through libraries. Also it can find function by type.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: You can read the code on Hackage (searching for it with Hoogle); but for `Functor`, there’s only one valid thing that `fmap` can do: the instance for `Either` is defined as `instance Functor (Either e)`, so `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Either e a -> Either e b`, and it *must* transform the `Right` branch (from `a` to `b`) and leave the `Left` branch untouched (`e`). In fact, if there’s a valid instance of `Functor` for a type, then it’s unique, which is why we have the `DeriveFunctor` extension to enable `deriving (Functor)`, but not e.g. `DeriveApplicative` (not unique).

Comment: Also, since `D` and `I` store the concrete types `Double` and `Int`, the type annotations should be unnecessary: ``if '.' `elem` str then D <$> readEither str else I <$> readEither str``

Comment: Well i need them on an `ADT` for pattern matching ....how can i achive that without wrapping them ?